# How can make a string used by a view translatable?

Tags: views, i18n-l10n

I have a *Events* view that is added from the [Fullcalendar View](https://www.drupal.org/project/fullcalendar_view) module. Is there a way to translate specific strings used from that view?

Answer (score 0):

In the Full calendar view dispaly, in "Format" section, there is "Settings" link. The modal window will open and you will see "Style options". Under "Display" accordion, there is setting called "Default Language" where you can select default language.

Also check if other translations settings are set correctly.

[image]

[image]